# Mysql relating two tables with functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one contains a list of teams, the other contains a list of schedules for these teams and score results.  I want to be able to update the teams table when I insert a row into the schedules table.  So for example if I have:

```
Teams table

Team1
Team2
```

.

```
Schedules table

team1, 3
team2, 1
```

what I want to be able to do is when the score fields are updated I need to update different fields in the teams table.  So when I update this schedule row,

It would insert 3 into one of the rows for team1, and 1 for the team2

Also I would like to be able to calculate the difference between the scores and also insert this into the teams table.

What would be the best way to implement this?

And I would need a function in order to do the comparison of the scores right?

Thanks,

So far I thought of doing something like this.

```
update table teams set teams.gamesplayed = teams.gameplayed +1  /*this would add one to the games played field because they just played.*/
```

then for the goals scored something like

```
update teams set teams.gf =
(

select t.goalsscored
from schedule t, teams s
where t.teamname = s.team1name AND )

)
```

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

you need add ON UPDATE and ON INSERT triggers to Teams table - thats all.
In trigger you can do anything you need. Of course you can create standalone function and call  it from triggers.

Comment: I'm not allowed to create triggers on godaddy account :(